# Getting objects with the same values (Flask)

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am new to Flask.
I have a database and I want to extract comments from it with the same parent ID and put them in the "comments" variable. How should I do it?
Comments DB model class:

```
class Comment(db.Model):
__tablename__ = 'comments'
id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
parent_id = db.Column(db.Integer(), nullable=False)
author = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
comment = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)

def __repr__(self):
    return f"<{self.id}>"
```

EDIT: parent_id is ID of arcticle.

Answer (score 0):

```
comments = Comment.query.filter_by(parent_id=same_parent_id).all()
```

This should do the job.
You can invoke this in your route when your model is imported there.